# Why am I getting an "execv(file, args)" error when using execl()?

Tags: python, os.execl

I am trying to use execl() to execute a new program but it keeps returning an execv() error saying that arg2 must not be empty.

```
if pid == 0:
    print("This is a child process")
    print("Using exec to another program")
    os.execl("example_prg_02.py")
```

Why would this be the case when using execl()? Does execl() require args too?

Comment: Try `os.execl("python", "example_prg_02.py")`

Comment: @rdas tried that too but it doesn't work. Returned the same error.

Comment: `execl` is just a wrapper around `execv` that lets arguments be passed as separate varargs, instead of as a single array of strings. It's still doing the same thing under the hood, just with a different calling convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"example_prg_02.py"` is not a path to executable file, you have to specify

- a path to executable file as a 1st parameter,
- the name of executable as a 2nd one,
- parameter(s) as 3rd (4th, 5th, ...)

So instead of your

```
os.execl("example_prg_02.py")
```

use

```
os.execl(sys.executable, "python", "example_prg_02.py")
```

(you have first `import sys`, of course).

`sys.executable` is the absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter.

---

*Addendum (from my comment):*

> Why error from `execv()`, when I used `execl()`?

Both `execv()` and `execl()` do the same thing, they differ in how command-line arguments are passed:

- if the last letter is **v** (**v**ariable number of arguments), you have to provide a *list or tuple* for argv (i.e. arguments),
- if the last letter is **l** (it probably means ***l**ist them* — for *constant* number of them), you have to provide argv as *individual arguments*.

`execl()` is only a “syntactical sugar” — **it calls internally** `execv()`, so you obtained the error from `execv()`.

Comment: That's perfect, works now and makes more sense to me, thanks. Do you know why it was returning a execv() error for an execl() function?

Comment: Both `execv()` and `execl()` do the same thing, they differ in how command-line arguments are passed: if the last letter is **v** (variable number of parameters), you have to provide a *list or tuple* for `argv` (i.e. arguments),  if it is **l** (it probably means *list them* - for constant number of them), you have to provide `argv` *as individual arguments* . —  `execl()` is only a “syntactical sugar” — it calls internally `execv()`, so you obtained `execv()` error.

Comment: what's the purpose of  "the name of executable as a 2nd one", since we already have "a path to executable file as a 1st parameter", so can the second parameter different from the first (I mean point to different executable) , what's the usage of the second one?

Comment: @DCdQ, you're very clever, no other asked this. The short answer is that almost all executables totally ignore this 2nd parameter (so you may write *any* string for it, e.g. `"abracadabra"`).  If you want to understand why, please write your comment as a new question and I will answer it.

Comment: Thanks, just raised :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403089/what-the-usage-of-2nd-parameter-in-os-execl