# What is the usage of 2nd parameter in os.execl()

Tags: python, linux

This question is inspired by the comments in [Why am I getting an “execv(file, args)” error when using execl()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171536/why-am-i-getting-an-execvfile-args-error-when-using-execl/61171705?noredirect=1#comment115610950_61171705).

When we use

```
os.execl(sys.executable, "python", "script.py")
```

The second parameter seems redundant for me, can anyone help explain why we need this parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old good days without graphical monitors and without mice, a text-only console (or even a teletype) was the only user interface between a user and the operating system.

This interface (Command Line Interface, CLI) instead of nowadays GUI (Graphical User Interface) forced a user to write commands, including ones for launching executables, instead of clicking on their icons.

(Most present operating systems still have this possibility, e.g. command-line window or PowerShell in Windows, or console / terminal window in GNU/Linux.)

The command line for launching a program had / has a form

```
              program  argument1  argument2 ...
```

where `program` (in those old days were only “programs” and “programmers”, no “applications” and “developers”) was the name of the executable file, often including a relative/absolute path.

The operating system launched `program`, passing to it *not only arguments* (`argument1`, `argument2`, ...), but — **as so-called 0<sup>th</sup> argument** — the `program` itself, too.
(In the same form, as it was typed, i.e. with or without a path, with or without a suffix / extension.)

So the launched program may found out, **how** it was launched. It may use this info for various purposes, for example

- to forbid launch it with the other name (["nomen est omen"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nomen_est_omen)) — so if you renamed an executable, you had a bad luck,
- to reach a different behavior in dependency of the launching name (some executables were / are installed with soft links with different names),
- for deriving the location of the helper / user files from the path, if it was explicitly used in the command.

Many contemporary programs (oh no, applications) still exploit the possibility to launch them from CLI with arguments, but (mostly) ignore the name of the program.

For example, in Windows you may use the command

```
       notepad somename.txt
```

to launch the Notepad with the already opened `somename.txt` file. Or — to not go far away — Python may launch your script with the command

```
       python somescript.py
```

Back to the main question:

The `os.execl()` function mimics the behavior of launching an application from CLI, giving the user (of this function) the possibility to specify the `program` as he or she needs. It is the second parameter of the `os.execl()` function. As I mentioned, the behavior of some — mainly old — programs depends on it.

---

*Addendum:*

Python has in its `sys.argv` list all command-line parameters — including the 0<sup>th</sup> argument in its `sys.argv[0]` element.

But note — if you launch your script with the command

```
python  /somefolder/somescript.py  xxx  7
```

from the `python` itself point of view *(not interesting for us)* the arguments are:

- the 0<sup>th</sup> argument is the string `"python"`,
- the 1<sup>st</sup> argument is the string `"/somefolder/somescript.py"`,
- the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument is the string `"xxx"`,
- the 3<sup>rd</sup> argument is the string `"7"`,

but from the `somescript.py` point of view — i.e. *what your script will obtain* — the arguments are

- the 0<sup>th</sup> argument is the string `"/somefolder/somescript.py"` — it is in `sys.argv[0]`,
- the 1<sup>st</sup> argument is the string `"xxx"` — it is in `sys.argv[1]`,
- the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument is the string `"7"` — it is in `sys.argv[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to a running program is, by convention, the name of the program *as entered by the user*. It doesn't have to be the actual executable file name, and often isn't, for example when the file is found in the `$PATH`.

The convention is followed by most shells, but is not enforced at the API level.